# Can't run example code referenced in Flask docs

Tags: python, flask

I am reading the Flask docs and want to use the examples they reference that are in the git repo.  However, the tutorials don't match the code in the repository, and I can't run them; I get the following error:

```
  @app.cli.command('initdb')
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'cli'
```

I used `pip install flask` to install Flask.  Why can't I run the repo code?

Answer (score 6):

You are reading the development docs, but using the latest stable release (0.10.1).  The current builds include many changes, including a cli.  To try out the latest code, use:

```
pip install https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tarball/master
```

To get something similar in the latest stable release, you either need to write your own commands or use a third-party extension such as Flask-Script.  A new extension, Flask-CLI, backports the new Click interface from master to the stable version.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I made it work:

change the function init_db()

```
def init_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()
```

And add this,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    app.run()
```

To run,

python flaskr.py

Answer (score 0):

Or you could manipulate the the example python script like this, take this [example](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/minitwit)
for instance

1. install click `pip install click`
2. modify minitwit.python, importing `FlaskCli` from `flask_cli` module
3. initialise it by adding `FlaskCLI(app)` under `app.config.from_envvar('MINITWIT_SETTINGS', silent=True)`